# Should gRPC channels be singleton, scoped or transient in .NET dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, grpc, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-5, grpc-dotnet

gRPC requests in .NET rely on channels, that must be shut down and disposed:

```cs
using var channel = Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.ForAddress("path to service");

//...do stuff...

await channel.ShutdownAsync();
```

I'm wrapping this in a .NET dependency injected service using `IServiceCollection`, should this be...

- Per-method - create and dispose the channel inside each method call.
- `AddTransient` - a new channel every time my service is requested, but only as long as it's needed.
- `AddScoped` - a new channel for each request, but keeping the channel open until the request is done.
- `AddSingleton` - a single new channel for the app.

I *think* `AddSingleton` is out as I'm not sure how one `GrpcChannel` will handle lots of parallel requests at the same time and I'd like to pass the `CancellationToken` for the current request.

Which puts the choice between `AddScoped` vs `AddTransient` vs per-method. Without a load of testing (and stumbling into all the pitfalls) I'm not sure what the best practice here is (I'm new to gRPC). Should I be closing the channel as soon as possible, or keeping it open and sharing it between calls?

Answer (score 5):

According to Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#client-performance :

> A channel represents a long-lived connection to a gRPC service.

and

> Channel and client performance and usage:
>
> - Creating a channel can be an expensive operation. Reusing a channel for gRPC calls provides performance benefits.
> - gRPC clients are created with channels. gRPC clients are lightweight objects and don't need to be cached or reused.
> - Multiple gRPC clients can be created from a channel, including different types of clients.
> - A channel and clients created from the channel can safely be used by multiple threads.
> - Clients created from the channel can make multiple simultaneous calls.    need to be cached or reused. Multiple gRPC clients can be
>   created    from a channel, including different types of clients. A
>   channel and    clients created from the channel can safely be used by
>   multiple    threads. Clients created from the channel can make
>   multiple    simultaneous calls.

According to grpc https://grpc.github.io/grpc/csharp-dotnet/api/Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.html :

> Class GrpcChannel Represents a gRPC channel. Channels are an
> abstraction of long-lived connections to remote servers. Client
> objects can reuse the same channel. Creating a channel is an expensive
> operation compared to invoking a remote call so in general you should
> reuse a single channel for as many calls as possible.

As always, it depends on what you are trying to do, but probably only single channel should be created by a Singleton. Also, if you really need to handle a heavy load, try using **SocketsHttpHandler.EnableMultipleHttp2Connections** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-5.0#connection-concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

Grcp clients should be registred with the GrcpClientFactory

```
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>(o =>
{
    o.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
});
```

(Surprisingly, this registers them as transient)

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/clientfactory?view=aspnetcore-6.0